# Loop, iloc and loc in Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hey guys I'm new to python, right now I'm starting to work with some libraries such as Pandas and Numpy. Recently, my teacher gives me this excercise, and I don't know which method I should use. Details are shown below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 1, 0, 3],
               'col2': [23, 4, 1, 1, 3], 
               'col3': [0, 5, 2, 1, 1],
               'col4': [1, 2, 6, 4, 0],
               'col5': [4, 15, 0, 2, 5],
               'loc': [1, 4, 2, 3, 2]})
```

1) col1 - col5: random number

2) loc: the location of the value.

3) Calculate 'val' which returns the value of each column, locations are given in 'loc'.

Example: In line 0, loc = 1, val = 23. In line 1 loc = 4, val = 15, etc.

The result should be like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 1, 0, 3],
               'col2': [23, 4, 1, 1, 3], 
               'col3': [0, 5, 2, 1, 1],
               'col4': [1, 2, 6, 4, 0],
               'col5': [4, 15, 0, 2, 5],
               'loc': [1, 4, 2, 3, 2],
                'val': [23, 15, 2, 4, 1]})
```

I have tried somthing like iloc and loc to calculate 'val'. However when the dataframe becomes larger I could not use this method anymore. Are there any faster way to calculate 'val'? Do I need to use loop to calculate 'val'?

```
df1 = df['loc']
df.iloc[0,df1[0]]
df.iloc[1,df1[1]]
df.iloc[2,df1[2]]
```

PS: Sorry for my bad English, but I really don't know how to explain this excercise in English, I just try my best :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy indexing, especially if performance is important:

```
df1['value'] = df1.values[np.arange(len(df1)), df1['loc']]
print (df1)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  loc  value
0     0    23     0     1     4    1     23
1     1     4     5     2    15    4     15
2     1     1     2     6     0    2      2
3     0     1     1     4     2    3      4
4     3     3     1     0     5    2      1
```

**Performance**:

```
#5000 rows
df1 = pd.concat([df1] * 1000, ignore_index=True)
In [73]: %timeit df1['value'] = df1.values[np.arange(len(df1)), df1['loc']]
266 µs ± 8.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [74]: %%timeit
    ...: result = []
    ...: for index, row in df1['loc'].iteritems():
    ...:      result.append(df1.iat[index, row])
    ...: df1['val'] = result
    ...: 
64 ms ± 753 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [75]: %timeit df1['value'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x['loc']], axis = 1)
243 ms ± 11.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know that we can use numpy in this case. I did read some documents and they said that numpy handle the large dataset better than pandas (may be just faster). But I think i have to code and read more to use both of these libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for-loop for this, where you increment a value to the range of the length of the column 'loc' (for example). With `.iloc` you can the select the correct row and value from the 'loc' column.

I'm not going to spill out the complete solution for you, but something along the lines of:

```
vals = [] # Create an empty list to hold the requested values
for i in range(len(df['loc'])): # Loop over the rows ('i')
    val = df.iloc[i, df['loc'][i]] # Get the requested value from row 'i'
    vals.append(val) # append value to list 'vals'
df['value'] = vals # Add list 'vals' as a new column to the DataFrame
```

edited to complete the answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, I have to admit that I tried this method but I don't know how to deal with the rest of the for loop. I understand the second line but don't know  how to apply for all :)

Comment: It's pretty easy. Just append val to a list and then add that as a new column to `df`. See my edit above...

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the series with index then using pd.iat[row int pos, column int pos] you will get exact value, from array of values you can create new series.

```
result = []
for index, row in df1['loc'].iteritems():
     result.append(df1.iat[index, row])
df1['val'] = result
```